# "Error: no children avalaible" in debugger views of Windsor

Tags: vb.net, castle-windsor

I have a problem with an Resolve and I'm trying that is mentioned in:
http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Debugger-views.ashx

But when I expand any node of my container (or kernel) variable it appears:
Error: no children avalaible.

However I can see:

```
All Components                        Count=6
All Services                          Count=5
Potentially Misconfigured Components  Count=1
Objects tracked by release policy     Count=0
```

I have installed VS 2010 SP1 and Castle Windsor 3.1.0.
What could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Solved it! It was a problem of VB.NET configuration: checking "Show all members for non-user objects in variables windows (VB only)" in menu Options\Debugging\General\Enable Just My Code (Managed Only) will works.